# Adding item in wishlist , but after adding showing red heart when i refresh i want that instant in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller, insert-update, instant

I am adding an item in wishlist in laravel , item is adding in wishlist and showing red heart but after adding when i refresh then only it shows red heart, how can i make it red heart instantly after adding in wihslist?

i have used ajax for pass the data

```
            <script>
                var user_id = {{ Auth::id() }};
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('.addtowishlist').click(function()
                    {
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers:{
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                        }
                    });
                    var product_id=$(this).data('productid');
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'/post_wishlist',
                        data:{
                            product_id:product_id,
                            user_id:user_id
                        },
                        success:function(reponse){
                            wishlistIcon.toggleClass('wishlist-added', response.inWishlist);
                        }
                    })
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

then i am inserting data into table using controller

```
          public function post_wishlist(Request $request)
            {
                if ($request->ajax()) {
                    $data = $request->all();
                    $pid = $data['product_id'];
                    $userid = $data['user_id'];

                    $wishlistExists = DB::table('wishlist')
                        ->where('pid', $pid)
                        ->where('userid', $userid)
                        ->exists();

                    if ($wishlistExists) {
                        DB::table('wishlist')
                            ->where('pid', $pid)
                            ->where('userid', $userid)
                            ->delete();
                    } else {
                        DB::table('wishlist')->insertOrIgnore([
                            'pid' => $pid,
                            'userid' => $userid,
                        ]);
                    }

                    return response()->json(['success' => true]);
                }
            }
```

and i am  displaying red heart using anchor tag

```
            <a href="#" id="addtowishlist" class="addtowishlist {{ ($productdata->inWishlist ? 'wishlist-added' : '') }}" data-productid="{{ $productdata->id }}">
                <i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x addtowishliststyle" aria-hidden="true" style="color: {{ ($productdata->inWishlist ? '#8B0000' : 'white') }}"></i>
            </a>
```

Comment: `wishlistIcon.toggleClass('wishlist-added ...` Where is `wishlistIcon` set? Any errors/warnings in your browser's DevConsole?

Comment: yes , i am getting an error this one Uncaught ReferenceError: wishlistIcon is not defined

Comment: So define it before you use it

Comment: does that will solve my question?

Comment: Why don't you try it out? It doesn't work now because you're trying to toggle a class on an element that hasn't been defined. _If_ you want to do that you should at least have an element to toggle that class on.